# How do I remove duplicates while adding values at the same time in Excel or Google sheets?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, spreadsheet

I'm very new with spreadsheets and I'm dealing with a ***very*** large data set and I need to filter the generated duplicates.
I got an A column which lists products and a B column which lists the amount of product sold in 1 order. There is also a C column which lists the client that made the order.

The problem is that our reporting system generates a new row for the product name with every order, so I cannot remove the duplicates for the product because the respective count is not consolidated.

So to put an example, lets say I got 3 separate orders for strawberry bubblegum, one order is for 100 units, another one for 50 and another one for 25.
Instead of having
Strawberry Bubblegum - 100,
Strawberry Bubblegum - 50,
Strawberry Bubblegum - 25

I want to have 
Strawberry Bubblegum - 175

As I said, the data set is huge (over 40k rows) and there's different products, so manually summing each count is not efficient at all.

Comment: I believe a [pivot table](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-PivotTable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-A9A84538-BFE9-40A9-A8E9-F99134456576) will do what you want

Answer (score 0):

**Follow this method to solve the issue:**

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in Cell `M83`, fill it down.

  `=IF(K83=K82,"",SUMIF(K$83:K$88,"="&K83,L$83:L$88))`
- Enter this array (CSE) formula in cell `K91`, finish with
  **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter and fill across.

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(K$83:K$88, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($K$89:K89, K$83:K$88), 0)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Show method works with Excel as well as with Google Sheet also.
- An alternative solution is, **Data Consolidation.**

*Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*